# Game Center turn-based match data is not saved and/or read

Tags: objective-c, ios6, game-center

I am planning to develop a turn-based game and is trying to understand how to communicate with Game Center and send and receive mach data. I have read about it and tested this for days now and just cannot get it to work as planned.

The only thing i try to do with the code below is to be able to save and then read the mach data. I am using two sandbox Game Center accounts for the turns.

The turns are sending the same data by pressing "endTurn" button. Every time i run the actual user is authenticated and the app is set up correctly (i believe).

This is a test app without any other purpose than test what i stated. Below is the code i use for the match data processing.

I would really appreciate any ideas and tips on what i may do wrong. Before i started serious testing i did post a similar question but that did not solve this problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447392/start-gamecenter-turn-based-match-and-initiate-match-data-for-the-very-first-tim.

I also try to catch the participants but with no success, which may mean that it is the problem when processing the completionhandler.

```
-(IBAction)endTurn:(id)sender {

[_gameDictionary setObject:@"The Object" forKey:@"The Key"];
NSLog(@"_gameDictionary: %@", _gameDictionary);

NSData *data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:_gameDictionary format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:nil];

GKTurnBasedParticipant *nextPlayer;

if (_match.currentParticipant == [_match.participants objectAtIndex:0]) {
    nextPlayer = [[_match participants] lastObject];
} else {
    nextPlayer = [[_match participants]objectAtIndex:0];
}

NSLog(@"_match.currentParticipant: %@", _match.currentParticipant);

[self.match endTurnWithNextParticipant:nextPlayer matchData:data completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"An error occured updating turn: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}];

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

_gameDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[self.match loadMatchDataWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *matchData, NSError *error) {
    NSDictionary *myDict = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:_match.matchData mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:nil errorDescription:nil];
    [_gameDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary: myDict];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"loadMatchData - %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];

NSLog(@"_gameDictionary: %@", _gameDictionary);

}
```

Output:

```
"gk-cdx" = "17.173.254.218:4398";
"gk-commnat-cohort" = "17.173.254.220:16386";
"gk-commnat-main0" = "17.173.254.219:16384";
"gk-commnat-main1" = "17.173.254.219:16385";
}
2013-02-11 22:44:11.707 GC_test1[8791:14f03] _gameDictionary: {
}
2013-02-11 22:44:13.894 GC_test1[8791:14f03] _gameDictionary: {
The Object = The Key;
}
2013-02-11 22:44:13.894 GC_test1[8791:14f03] _match.currentParticipant: (null)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `_match.currentParticipant` evaluates to `nil` is troubling. I suspect that `_match` was never initialized, or is `nil`, or that it was not obtained from a Game Center facility such as `loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:`, the `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController`, or using `findMatchForRequest:withCompletionHandler:`.

For a new match, if created through any of these facilities, `currentParticipant` would be guaranteed to represent the local player. You are not allowed to instantiate a `GKTurnBasedMatch` yourself.

To resolve this issue at least for testing, you could assign a new `_match` from within the completion handler of `findMatchForRequest:withCompletionHandler:`. Only then should you be allowed to press your test button.